# SQL: How Do i get the following Monday, 2 weeks after the customer registered with us?

Tags: mysql, sql, metabase

I have a list of customers who all registered on different dates, I was wondering how do I find the following Monday 2 weeks after registration?

For example if a person registered on a Sunday then the following Monday would technically fall on their second week and 1 day after registration. while someone who registers on a Monday their following Monday would technically fall on their 3rd week after registration.

Comment: Which SQL vendor (MySQL, Postgres, etc...) do you use?

Comment: get the day of week as n then you want date + 7 + 7-n days (if the day of week returns 1 on monday)

Comment: I use MySQL  currently

Comment: People are having trouble understanding your description of the dates you're trying to return. Could you provide some specific examples of Sunday and Monday dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monday is the 2 dayofweek so you should add  14+2 - your_dayoftheweek  days to your date

```
 SELECT DATE_ADD(your_date, INTERVAL (16 - DAYOFWEEK(your_date)) DAY);
```

or as suggested  by barmar

```
SELECT case when DAYOFWEEK(your_date) = 2 
        then DATE_ADD(your_date, INTERVAL 21  DAY)
        else   DATE_ADD(your_date, INTERVAL (16 - DAYOFWEEK(your_date)) DAY)
    END ;
```

Comment: If they register on Monday, he wants the result to be 21 days later.

Comment: I think you need `IF` or `CASE` to handle that special case.

Comment: Why did you change 16 to 9?

Answer (score 0):

scaisEdge is close, but not quite there. On Sunday, the interval added will be 15 days, which is actually 3 Mondays later. The code below will get you what you need:

```
SELECT (your_date + INTERVAL ((CASE WHEN dayofweek(your_date) = 1 THEN 7 ELSE 14 END) + (2 - dayofweek(your_date))) DAY) AS 2_mondays_from_now;
```

Since Sunday's day of the week is the only one smaller than Monday's, you need this case logic. This holds true for any day of the week that occurs numerically before your desired day of the week (e.g. If you wanted Wednesday, you'd have to case for Sunday, Monday, and Tuesday)

**EDIT**

I have written a function in MySQL that generalizes this problem to any day of the week, and any number of weeks after (or before) the input date:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dow_in_x_wks (indate DATE, dow INT, wks INT)
RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
RETURN (indate + INTERVAL (
(CASE WHEN dayofweek(indate) < dow THEN (wks - 1) * 7 ELSE wks * 7 END) + (dow - dayofweek(indate))) DAY);
```

Comment: Isn't 15 the correct number of days? The question says "second week and 1 day". 2 weeks + 1 day = 15.

Comment: Not sure, I think the phrasing in the question is unclear. I interpreted second week and one day after registration to be "in the second week (i.e. 7 days have completed) and one day after registration" to be 8 days later (7 + 1)

Comment: I've asked the OP to clarify, since I agree that his wording isn't clear. But he also said that when they register on Monday it should be 3 weeks later.

Comment: @Barmar I do not see any comment from Gus clarifying what he means. My interpretation is based upon the title. Also, in the original question, the wording describes days as falling "on weeks", and not after weeks have completed. He refers to the 'following Monday', not the Monday after next.

Comment: He hasn't responded to my comment yet.